# Can't activate xp_cmdshell for one session only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, xp-cmdshell

I tried activating xp_cmdshell just before using it in my nightly SP (running on a SQL job) and then turning it off, but it didn't work. The history (image below) seems to imply that the `RECONFIGURE` keyword isn't working.

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NightlySP]

AS
BEGIN

--Allow xp_cmdshell to be used for the duration of this session only
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  

-- To enable the feature.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE; 

/*
...rest of SP where I use xp_cmdshell...
*/    

--Turn off xp_cmdshell
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  

-- To enable the feature.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;  

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE; 

END
```

Comment: If your account running SQL Server agent isn't a `sysadmin` it'll lack the permissions to do the above (which it **should not** have). In truth turning the feature on and off is somewhat pointless. By default only an `sa` can use `xp_cmdshell`, and if you're leaving it as that then no actual problems are exposed; if they access to use `xp_cmdshell` they have access to enable it. If you plan for your `sysadmin`s to be able to use `xp_cmdshell` then you might as well leave it enabled; having it off is a 0.05 second speedbumb for a compromised `sysadmin` account

Comment: In fact I'd go further and argue that a script that toggles `xp_cmdshell` on and off is itself more of a security risk than just enabling the setting (with documentation that you did that, and why you're using it), since it makes it harder to see if `xp_cmdshell` is being used or not, and excluding only this specific use from automated security audits when they happen to look at the server is much harder. It's also a global solution to a local problem: as soon as two jobs need to do this concurrently, they can unwittingly sabotage each other.

Comment: Ah ok, then I'll just turn it on and not bother with this. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

To run xp_cmdshell with least-privileges configure an [xp_cmdshell Proxy Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#xp_cmdshell-proxy-account), specifying a Windows identity with appropriate privileges, and grant execute on xp_cmdshell to the account that runs the job.

Otherwise, the identity running the script must be a sysadmin, and xp_cmdshell runs the OS commands as the SQL Server Service Account.

The SQL Server service account shouldn't be highly privileged, but it always has file-level access to all databases and backups.  Attached databases are protected from OS-level access but backups and detached databases, are vulnerable.  And the Service account can accumulate privileges like the privilege to view uninitialized free space on local disks (aka "perform volume maintenance tasks" required for instant file initialization), or network permissions for file shares.

So either leave it on, and run the job as a sysadmin, knowing the risks, or provision a lower-privilege Windows user to run the job.  You can use a single local Windows account for both the job owner and the xp_cmdshell proxy account.